# VB. If with multiple Or inside

Tags: vba, excel

I want to put this If in a macro but it gives me an error all the time. I dont know if "Or" is used correctly or not.

```
 Dim SMAT As String
 SMAT = "blahblahblah"
    (...)  
 If Cells(h + 2, 24) <> SMAT Or SMBE Or SMES Or SMFR Or SMGB Or SMGR Or SMRO1 Or SMRO2 Or SMRO3 Or SMDE Then
        C(j) = Cells(h + 2, 5)
```

Comment: What is the code *supposed* to do? Do you want to check that `Cells(h + 2, 24)` is not equal to all of those `SM*` strings? If so, you'll need to repeat the test each time. `If (Cells(h + 2, 24) <> SMAT) Or (Cells(h + 2, 24) <> SMBE) Or ...` Parentheses help.

Comment: I still think they should be AND's not OR's but of course using 'like' operator was rubbish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Select Case` block instead:

```
Select Case Cells(H + 2, 24).Value
    Case SMAT, SMBE, SMES, SMFR, SMGB, SMGR, SMR01, SMR02, SMR03, SMDE
    Case Else
        c(j) = Cells(H + 2, 5).Value
End Select
```

---

Or another way using `Evaluate()`, just for variety*:

```
varConditions = Array(SMAT, SMBE, SMES, SMFR, SMGB, SMGR, SMR01, SMR02, SMR03, SMDE)

If Evaluate("ISERROR(MATCH(" & Cells(H + 2, 24).Value & ",{" & _
    Join(varConditions, ",") & "},0))") Then
        c(j) = Cells(H + 2, 5).Value
End If
```

** This Evaluate method will work when the array contains numbers - if you are using strings you would have to wrap each string in additional quotation marks*

Comment: Plus 1 for the SELECT CASE.

Comment: the Select Case block does exactly the opposite haha 

thanks anyway for your help

Comment: @PedroLastra sorry, missed a line - I've just changed it so that it fits your logic

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correction

```
Dim SMAT As String
SMAT = "blahblahblah"
'(...)
If Cells(H + 2, 24) <> SMAT Or _
   Cells(H + 2, 24) <> SMBE Or _
   Cells(H + 2, 24) <> SMES Or _
   Cells(H + 2, 24) <> SMFR Or _
   Cells(H + 2, 24) <> SMGB Or _
   Cells(H + 2, 24) <> SMGR Or _
   Cells(H + 2, 24) <> SMRO1 Or _
   Cells(H + 2, 24) <> SMRO2 Or _
   Cells(H + 2, 24) <> SMRO3 Or _
   Cells(H + 2, 24) <> SMDE Then
    c(j) = Cells(H + 2, 5)
End If
```

[Or Operator (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx)

The error is because you are trying to "talk" to VBA like a person do, but the `or` does not take the parameter of another `or`. You need to tell in every parameter of each `or` to tell the complete `logical test`

```
firstCheck = a > b Or b > c
firstCheck = Logical_test Or Logical_test
```

Comment: Done! 
Thanks Cody Gray and ElbertV

Comment: IMHO the syntax is right but the logic is wrong. Sorry!